# Display the title of a node's menu parent using Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am trying to display the title of a node's menu parent in a Views block display.
For example, my menu has "About Us" --> "Our History". In "Our History," I would like to display "About Us" in a block using views.

I have searched through the Drupal Views issues and come up with nothing. I might even be approaching this in the incorrect way.

Thanks for your help!

**Update:** To see what I mean, please visit http://bpc.paulsham.com/about-us/history. I would like the text on the image banner to say "About Us".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something Views can do by default. Instead, you may consider using the [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, which allows you to craft blocks of menu links that the core menu module is incapable of doing.

For example, if your 'About Us' node is in the primary links menu, you could create a menu block that showed the children of that node. This would be dynamic so that when you viewed another top-level item of the primary links, the block would only display the children menu items of that link.

Comment: Thanks @jhedstrom. I'm not looking for links to the parent. I updated my question with a link to show what I mean.